# Chain http requests when using service file

Tags: angular

I wish to combine 2 http requests together to make this a little more elegant however most examples I see online use `mergemap` however they are not making the http requests via a service file. Any ideas on how I can approach this? I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getMatrixData();
}

getMatrixData() {

      this.httpService.getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix()
          .subscribe((res) => {

              this.packageListItems = res.body;
              this.getGradeItems();

          });

  }

getGradeItems() {
      this.httpService.getHospitalityGradesList()
          .subscribe((res) => {

              this.allGrades = res.body;
              this.makeMatrix();
          });
  }

makeMatrix()
{
console.log("Now combine data");
}
```

My service file just returns the following:

```
getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("apiPath", { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response', headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "bearer " + this.getUserToken() + " ") });
    }

getHospitalityGradesList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("apiPath", { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response', headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "bearer " + this.getUserToken() + " ") });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your service file

Comment: @YogendraR sure I've just updated :)

Comment: @Arcteezy I know, but as mentioned in the post I'd like to be able to make this more elegant to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with a `mergeMap`, or the more semantically correct one `concatMap`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.this.httpService.getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix().pipe(
    concatMap((res) => {
      this.packageListItems = res.body;

      return this.httpService.getHospitalityGradesList()
    }),
    tap((res) => this.allGrades = res.body)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    this.makeMatrix()
  });
}
```

---

if the second request does not depend on the first request, you can also use `forkJoin`, which is again semantically more correct than `combineLatest`. You have to pass in an array of observables, of an object map. The observable paramater list is deprecated:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  forkJoin([
    this.httpService.getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix(),
    this.httpService.getHospitalityGradesList()
  ]).subscribe(([ packageListItems, allGrades ]) => {
    this.pacakgeListItems = packageListItems.body;
    this.allGrades = allGrades.body;
  });
}
```

---

A third option would be to have the nice possibility of using the `async` pipe from angular, which will make your code even cleaner:

```
readonly packageListItems$ = this.httpService.getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix().pipe(
  map(({ body }) => body), 
  shareReplay(1)
);

readonly allGrades$ = this.httpService.getHospitalityGradesList().pipe(
  map(({ body }) => body), 
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

All you need to do when you use this in your template is:

```
<div *ngFor="let package of packageListItems$ | async"></div>
```

This way you don't have to subscribe in your component, which is sort of frowned upon, and also when you navigate away from the component and the request is not finished yet, it is already automatically unsubscribed and won't trigger any unwanted effeccts.

<sub>I've added the `shareReplay` for convenience. This will replay the last value on subscription. This way if you subscribe to it in your code to get the last value, it does not fire the http request again but just returns the last value</sub>

side-note 2: If you do use `forkJoin`, make sure your `httpService` catches any network error it might receive. If one of the observables fail, the entire `forkJoin` will fail and any request that did succeed will not reach the subscriber. So do use `catchError` inside your `httpService` and perhaps return an empty array when the response is supposed to be an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a little confused: Do you mean contactMap or concatMap? I'm guessing there was a typo there?

Comment: Ah no worries thanks so much. So concatMap preferred than mergeMap? And forkJoin preferred than combineLatest?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward Your http requests are requests that finish after the first emit, both combinateLatest and mergeMap are there for observables which could actually be a stream of emits. In your case they will both do the exact same, but it's nice to know the difference and when (not) to use them. If one request does not depend on the other, and you want them to run simultaneously, you use `forkJoin`. If you want them to run sequentially, you use `concatMap`. If it can have multiple emits, you use `mergeMap`, if you want the inner observable to cancel on the parent emit, you use `switchMap`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make use of `forkJoin` that will execute both requests together

```
makeMatrix() {
forkJoin(this.httpService.getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix(), 
this.httpService.getHospitalityGradesList())
 .subscribe(
  ([r1, r2]) => {

  }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combineLatest` from `rxjs`.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest([
        this.httpService.getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix(),
        this.httpService.getHospitalityGradesList()
    ]).subscribe(
       ([res1, res2]) => {
          // res1 contains response of getPackageAvailabilityListForPricingMatrix()
          // res2 contains response of getHospitalityGradesList()
          this.makeMatrix();
       }
    );
}
```

P.S. : This is only possible when your service function returns `observable` and you dont have dependent API calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't seen combineLatest before. Is it newer than mergeMap?

Comment: May be newer than mergeMap but not very new... it was already there in previous versions of rxjs.